# Rails Active Admin Filters Not working for Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a rails 4.0.4 application and use Active Admin for the CMS. 
The Active Admin filters for date time attributes were working and once I upgraded to Ruby 2.2.4 This stop working.

My Gem file

```
ruby "2.2.4"
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

in /app/admin/user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
      filter :first_name
      filter :last_name
      filter :email
      filter :mobile
      filter :created_at
      filter :promo_code
end
```

When a filter is applied it filters the data except for created_at. Instead it displays all users without considering the filter applied for created_at field.

The query string is.

```
/admin/users?utf8=✓&q[created_at_gteq]=2016-02-26&commit=Filter&order=id_desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue and for anyone who got this issue,

Using active admin "1.0.0.pre1" resolved the issue

```
gem 'activeadmin', "1.0.0.pre1"
```